# .NET app won't run on Windows 2008. Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: vb.net, jet

I have a .NET app written VB.NET version 3.5 on a 32 bit machine. It manually creates a schema.ini file and uses the following code to connect to a .csv file.

```
        varConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & _
        varFile.DirectoryName & "\;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited"""
```

This works fine on my 32 bit machine, however when it is deployed to a Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard machine, it fails with the following error "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine"

I have read that I need to build the install for the application under x86. I have tried this, but it does not solve my problem.

I also read that installing this (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554F536-8C28-4598-9B72-EF94E038C891&displaylang=en) would resolve the issue. I tried installing, but this did not help either.

I should also note that this is a console application, not an ASP.NET application. (IIS is out of the picture here)

Any ideas of what I need to do to fix this?

Thanks

I have also tried installing the Access runtime found at (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?familyid=d9ae78d9-9dc6-4b38-9fa6-2c745a175aed&displaylang=en) Still no luck.

Comment: "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0' provider is not registered on the local machine" -- seems to indicate the problem

Comment: What do I need to do to make it registered? I thought installing the Office 2007 System Driver: Data Connectivity Components would have done that.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to that download page again, scroll down and follow instructions.

Comment: I have updated my connection string based on the instructions on that download page. Now it just get "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."